# Binary tree deletion with minimum function

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

so basicly I have a class for binary tree and I really want to make deletion function but I keep messing something up.

So here is what's working:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, number=None, par=None):
        self.number=number
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.parent=par

class tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dummy=node()
    def Add(self, num, nd=None):
        if(nd==None):
            nd=self.dummy.right
        if(nd==None):# jeśli drzewo było puste
            self.dummy.right=node(num, par=self.dummy)
            return
        if(nd.number>num):
            if(nd.left==None):
                nd.left=node(num, par=nd)
                return
            else:
                self.Add( num, nd.left)
                return
        else:
            if(nd.right==None):
                nd.right=node(num, par=nd)
                return
            else:
                self.Add( num, nd.right)

    def Find(self, num_to_search, _node="nic"):
        if(_node=="nic"):
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if(_node==None):
            return None
        if(_node.number==num_to_search):
            return _node
        if(_node.number>num_to_search):
            return self.Find(num_to_search, _node.left)
        return self.Find(num_to_search, _node.right)

    def PrintID(self, _node="nic"):
        if _node=="nic":
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if _node==None:
            return
        self.PrintID(_node.left)
        print(_node.number, end=",")
        self.PrintID(_node.right)

    def KeysSum(self, _node="nic"): #suma kluczy
        if _node=="nic":
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if _node==None:
            return 0
        return self.KeysSum(_node.left)+self.KeysSum(_node.right)+_node.number
        
    def Height(self, _node="nic"): #wysokość 
        if _node=="nic":
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if _node==None:
            return 0
        right=self.Height(_node.right)+1
        left=self.Height(_node.left)+1
        if right>left:
            return right
        else:
            return left

    def Myk(self, _node="nic", depth=0): #rysuje drzewo
        if _node=="nic":
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if _node==None:
            return
        self.Myk(_node.right, depth+1)
        for i in range(depth):
            print("  ",end="")
        print(_node.number)
        self.Myk(_node.left, depth+1)
        
    def Minimum(self, _node="nic"): #zwraca węzeł o najmniejszym kluczu
        if _node=="nic":
            _node=self.dummy.right
        if _node==None:
            return
        else:   
            while _node.left != None:
                _node=_node.left
            return _node

    def Nastepnik(self, _node="nic"):
        if _node==None:
            return None
        if _node.right!=None:
            return self.Minimum(_node.right)
        par=_node.parent
        while par!=None and _node==par.right:
            _node=par
            par=_node.parent
        return par
```

And now I want to use Minimum to do delete function. I did that:

```
def Del(self, _node):
        if _node==None:
            return
        if _node.right==None and _node.left==None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=None
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=None
            return
        if _node.right!=None and _node.left==None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=_node.right
                _node.right.parent=par
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=_node.left
                _node.right.parent=par
            return
        if _node.right==None and _node.left!=None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=_node.left
                _node.left.parent=par
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=_node.right
                _node.left.parent=par
            return
        if _node.right!=None and _node.left!=None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=_node.right
                _node.right.parent=par
                self.Minimum(par)=_node.left
                _node.left.parent=self.Minimum(par)
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=_node.left
                _node.left.parent=par
                self.Minimum(par)=_node.left
                _node.left.parent=self.Minimum(par)
            return
```

but it's not working. Any ideas how to fix that? I figured it's a problem with how I try to use Minimum function but honestly I have no idea how to do it differently. I also really struggle with classes so you need to forgive me for being such a moron...

Comment: Why do you have a dummy node? Does it help in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your `Del` method:

- `par` is not defined.
- `self.Minimum(par)=_node.left` is not a valid assignment (syntax error).
- The assignment `par.left=_node.left` is wrong when actually `_node.right` is the one that is not `None`. It should be `par.left=_node.right`. And a similar mixup occurs in the next `if` block
- The case where `self.Minimum` is called is not attempting to do the job in the advised way. Besides the syntax error, there are double calls of `self.Minimum` which are not guaranteed the same result when you have just attempted to change the tree. Instead, you should just transfer the value of the minimum node to the node to be deleted, and then delete that minimum node instead.

Here is your code with minimal corrections:

```py
    def Del(self, _node):
        if _node==None:
            return
        par = _node.parent  # added
        if _node.right==None and _node.left==None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=None
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=None
            return
        if _node.right!=None and _node.left==None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=_node.right
                _node.right.parent=par
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=_node.right  # corrected
                _node.right.parent=par
            return
        if _node.right==None and _node.left!=None:
            if _node==par.right:
                par.right=_node.left
                _node.left.parent=par
            if _node==par.left:
                par.left=_node.left  # corrected
                _node.left.parent=par
            return
        # complete rewrite:
        minimum = self.Minimum(_node.right)
        _node.number = minimum.number
        self.Del(minimum)
```

Some other remarks:

- There should be no need to have a `dummy` node.
- There should be no need to have `parent` references
- Method names are commonly written in either camelCase or snake_case, not in PascalCase.
- Avoid the use of the "nic" default value hack
- Don't write an `if` condition when that condition can only be True (as it is the only case that ever gets to execute that `if`).